# What does the GNU ld --undefined option do?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, gnu, ld

Can somebody explain what the GNU ld option `--undefined` does?

Working on a [LiteOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiteOS) project. The app is linked with many `-u` options. For example `-utask_shellcmd`.

The [GNU linker manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_node/ld_3.html) for `--undefined=symbol` simply says:

> Force symbol to be entered in the output file as an undefined symbol. Doing this may, for example, trigger linking of additional modules from standard libraries.

So the symbol will be included in the output file as an undefined. What if the symbol is already defined in one of the linked obj files? If it is really undefined, when the linking of additional modules will happen and how does that happen?

Comment: Compiler looks at your translation unit and creates a compiled object file. Part of what that file has is a symbol table of what external symbols the object file referred to that are not part of that object. Those are the undefined symbols.

Comment: In a normal hosted environment, the way that `main()` gets called is because the start-up code (`crt0.o` or similar) calls the function — but doesn't define it, so the linker looks for the definition in your object files.  The `--undefined=symbol` option tells the linker that `symbol` should be sought in amongst the object files and libraries that are scanned.  I haven't checked whether its position on the linker command line matters.  If the symbol is already defined, it won't matter (and won't be linked again).  If it is still undefined at the end of linking, the linking may fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `-u` option is only relevant when archive (`.a`) libraries are involved (maybe also `.so` libraries with `--as-needed` in effect).

Unlike individual object files (`.o`) on the linking command line, which are all linked in the order in which they appear, object files from an archive library are only linked when they satisfy one or more undefined symbol references at the point they appear in the link command line order. Once once `.o` file from the archive is pulled into the link, the process is repeated recursively, so that if it introduces more undefined symbol references, other object files from the same (or later) archives will be pulled in to satisfy them.

Using `-u` allows you to cause a particular symbol (and, indirectly, all dependencies of the object file it was defined in) to be pulled into the link. Of course you could just put all `.o` files on the command line directly, without using any archive libraries, but by using libraries you can *avoid linking unused object files* (this is especially useful if large parts of the code may be unused depending on build-time-configurable settings in other files!) while getting the ones you need.

Comment: Basically, it could cause an unused symbol to be linked into the resulting binary. Correct? Then why would that be needed?

Comment: @minghua: Indeed, for normal hosted applications, the undefined symbol dependency tree rooted at `main` (via `crt1.o`) is sufficient to get everything you need. But for a freestanding project like a kernel, you may need to define your own root(s). Also, either way - but this is more common with bare-metal/kernel programming where it's valid to be making assumptions about your linker - object files which are not part of the main symbol dependency tree could play a role in the final output via special sections that get inserted into tables by a linker script, etc.

Comment: One special case of this that *is* portable is constructors for static objects (in C++, or via GNU C attributes to make a function a "ctor" that runs at startup). Pulling in an object file that's otherwise unused can alter the program behavior by causing static ctors in that file to be linked and run at startup.